# Git can not find files in branch but will not commit because a file is too large

Tags: git, pickle, large-files

Problem: I have a git branch that I am trying to push to remote.  The push fails with the following message:

```
Writing objects: 100% (881/881), 31.27 MiB | 821.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 881 (delta 691), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: warning: File one.pickle is 79.43 MB; this is larger than
GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: 2056a7d69782753a64379d283d737b94
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File two.pickle is 173.14 MB; this exceeds
GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/blah/blahblah.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to     
'https://github.com/blah/blahblah.git'
```

So my natural reaction is to remove the files from the branch history entirely.  The problem is git can not find the files. They exist nowhere but on the commit when it errors out.

I also tried

```
git rm --cached one.pickle
```

I also tried filter-branch

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm one.pickle' HEAD
```

but received the following..

```
Rewrite 554f5c56e41049394b3714dba1b409f30ca76f8 (1/391)rm:
one.pickle: No such file or directory
tree filter failed: rm one.pickle
```

Question: How can I get my commit to push to remote while thinking one.pickle and two.pickle do not exists which is seems they don't?

Comment: `git ls-files | grep one.pickle` should show you its location

Comment: or maybe it was committed in a previous commit and removed again, but that makes that it is still present in your history. In that case you'll have to rewrite your history to remove it completely from your history

Comment: You probably want `'rm -f one.pickle'`, as the `-f` will make it ignore nonexistent files.

Comment: I suggest searching the output of `git log --name-status` for the file names.  If the file existed previously and was deleted, you will be able to see the commit that removed the file (as well as the one that added it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `git filter-branch` you need to use a command that do not fail.

In this case it will fail on commits where the file has not yet been added.
Change the command to ignore missing files:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm -f one.pickle' HEAD
```